# flutter: Exception Happened: Bad state: No element in XML

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

I have a working function to pull data from an XML API

I have added a parameter in the `model` to pull one extra number, so have based it on my other calls for a number data

PublishedLineName works well, and it is a `number` like DestinationRef. However, not every block in the List of data contains a `DestinationRef`, so when I call it comes back `null` like the `.first` builder says it will.

However, when I change it from `.first.text` to `toString()` it returns the data but with XML schema around it so is not a usable number.

How should I adapt

```
     vaElement.findAllElements('DestinationRef').first.text,
```

To be prepared for a null and carry on pulling the present data?

My model is here, and the error is on the highlighted line above. If I change it to a `('Ref')` number that is present in each element of the list it returns fine.

```
...
    this.publishedLineName,
    this.destinationRef,

  String? publishedLineName;
  String? destinationRef;

        publishedLineName: 
            vaElement.findAllElements('PublishedLineName').first.text,
            
        destinationRef: 
            vaElement.findAllElements('DestinationRef').first.text,
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see from [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/xml/latest/xml/XmlFindExtension/findAllElements.html) that `findAllElements` returns an `Iterable`.

`Iterable.first` throws if there are no elements.

So, you need to check if there are any elements found (i.e. whether a sub tag exists with that key in the XML document):

```
final elements = vaElement.findAllElements('DestinationRef');
return elements.isEmpty ? null /*or something else*/ : elements.first.text;
```

Put this in a re-usable method, as you'll use it often.

```
String? getFirstMatchingElement(XMLElement x, String key) {
  final elements = x.findAllElements(key);
  return elements.isEmpty ? null : elements.first.text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are circa 20 blocks within the list, only 1 doesn't contain the data DestinationRef, the rest all do each time it is called. Do I have to place that in the XML Model or within the .dart doc to call the data?

Comment: In that line of code you show: `destinationRef: getFirstMatchingElement(vaElement, 'DestinationRef'),`

Comment: Have implemented and works perfectly, thank you Richard.